# how to select max(column) and a column in the same request teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, greatest-n-per-group, teradata-sql-assistant

I need to select the max of a column and the column itself in the same request using TeraData SQL Assitant

I tried :

```
select distinct id, col1, max(col1) from tab where id='myId' group by col1,id;
```

I tried also :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.col1 FROM tab a
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(a.col1) AS maxINT,id FROM tab GROUP BY id)x
ON  a.id = x.id
WHERE a.I_INTNE_DOSS_FIN = 'myId' ;
```

The problem I have the value of col1 in both col1 and max(col1)

Any idea please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share sample  data with required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the *row* where `col1` has the greater value for each `id`.

In Teradata, you can do this with `row_number()` and `qualify`:

```
select *
from tab
qualify row_number() over(partition by id order by col1 desc) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want both details and aggregate in the same Select. This is easy using *Windowed Aggregates*, probably

```
select id, col1, max(col1) over ()
from tab 
where id='myId'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want one row.  If so:

```
select top (1) t.*
from tab 
where id = 'myId'
order by col1 desc;
```